# Cannot pass yield value to another function

Tags: python, function, generator

I have these two functions:

```
def getItems(r, c):
     **do something**
     **find and yield four values a, b, c, d**
     yield (a,b,c,d)

def mainfunction(data): 
     reader = csv.reader(records)
     for row in reader:
         a,b,c,d = getItems(row, c)
     yield (a,b,c,d)
```

However, when I run the file, I keep getting an error :

```
a, b, c, d = getItems(r, c)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 1)
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with this!

Comment: Where are the values `r` and `c` you attempt to pass to `getItems` coming from?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry r is supposed to be row, and c is a dictionary that I'm passing to get matching items in each row. I've edited.

Answer (score 2):

`yield` converts the function to a generator, each `yield` being one item of the iterator. The tuple is an other item. So your `getItem` returns an iterable (~sequence) of tuples, even if it only yields one tuple, it's still an iterator of tuples.

Just replace the `yield` by `return`. Or if there's an actual reason for it to be there, you need to iterate the result of `getItem`.

You could also yield the individual values such that `getItem()` is an iterable of 4 elements but that doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: I'm supposed to use yield only, how do you suggest I iterate over the yield?

Comment: That... doesn't really make any sense. But you can either `for a, b, c, d in getItem()`, or you can replace `yield a, b, c, d` by `yield a; yield b; yield c; yield d`. Both seem stupid though.

Comment: using the first method, I get a new error: yield (a, b, c, d)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment